# Reading in a positive int and transform every digit of that number in an even-odd way

Tags: python, python-3.x

So what I need to do is read in a number and transform every digit.

- add 2 to an odd digit
- subtract 3 from an even digit (watch out for negative numbers!)
- zero stays 0

> **input** 
> 14502

> **wanted output**
> 31701
>
> **Current output**
> 14504

Below is what I have for now, I can read every digit in a for loop but I don't know how to transorm them one by one.

```
num = int(input("Enter a number:"))


for digit in str(num):
print(digit)
if (num % 2)==0:
    print(num + 2)
else:   
    print(num - 3)
```

**ALSO NO IMPORTS**

Comment: What is the difference between your current output and your desired output? Please edit this into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
num = input("Enter a number:")
new_num = []
single_number = ''
for digit in num:
    digit = int(digit)
    if digit == 0:
        new_num.append(digit)
    elif (digit % 2)!=0:
        digit = digit+2
        new_num.append(digit)
    elif (digit % 2)==0:
        digit = digit-3
        if digit>=0:
            new_num.append(digit)
        else:
            digit = digit*(-1)
            new_num.append(digit)
print(new_num)

# for single int instead of array
for digit in new_num:
    digit = str(digit)
    single_number = single_number+digit
print(single_number)
```

new_number is array of digits single_number is the final number you want.

Answer (score 0):

is your code missing the indent after the for loop? I know that may not solve the question but is that another issue with your code or just a formatting issue here on stack?

```
num = int(input("Enter a number:"))

    for digit in str(num):
        print(digit)
        if (num % 2)==0:
            print(num + 2)
        else:   
            print(num - 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = int(input("Enter a number:"))
print(len(str(num)))
finaloutput = []
for i in range(len(str(num))):
    digit = num%10
    if digit%2==0:
        if digit - 3 < 0:
            digit = 0
        else:
            digit = digit - 3
    else:
        digit = digit + 2
    finaloutput.append(digit)
    num = num //10
print(finaloutput)
string=""
for i in range(len(finaloutput)):
    string = string + str(finaloutput[i])
print(string[::-1])
```

Might be a big scuffed but gets the job done. Substract 3 from even, add 2 to odds, and watch for zeros.

output:

```
Enter a number:14502
5
[0, 0, 7, 1, 3]
31700
```

I put it so if an even number sub 3 is less than zero it jus stays zero, bc thats how I understood it. You can easily modify the code to suit your need and in accordance with your task or whatever

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
num = 9876543210

l = [int(c) for c in str(s)]

l = [min(c, 7) + 2 if c % 2 else max(c, 4) - 3 if c != 0 else c for c in l]

out = int(''.join(str(c) for c in l))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
9593715130
```

Details:

```
9 -> 9 (else 12)
8 -> 5 (-3)
7 -> 9 (else 10)
6 -> 3 (-3)
5 -> 7 (+2)
4 -> 1 (-3)
3 -> 5 (+2)
2 -> 1 (else -1)
1 -> 3 (+2)
0 -> 0 (do nothing)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation based on your solution. It can only handle integers though. And there is one case which you have not specified which is

- what to do when the digit is 9? As `9 + 2 = 11` and 11 is not a digit but could well be what you want in your algorithm?

In this implementation 9 is turned to 1.

```py
def calc_on_digits(num: str):
    result: str = ""

    for digit in num:
        digit = int(digit)
        if digit == 0:
            result += "0"
            continue
        if digit % 2 == 0:
            # in case it get negative take the absolute value
            digit = abs(digit - 3)
        else:
            digit += 2
            # in case its 9 the result would be 11 -> make it one
            digit = digit % 10
        result += str(digit)
    return result

# string in this implementation can only contain valid integer values
print(calc_on_digits("14502"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot calculate modulo from string. Also you have to perform the comparison per digit, not for the whole number.

```
num = input("Enter a number:")  # no need to cast to int just to transform back to str below

new_number = ""
for digit in num:
    digit = int(digit)
    print(digit)
    if (digit % 2) = 0:
        tmp = digit + 2
        if tmp >= 10:
            tmp = 0
    else:
        tmp = digit - 3
        if tmp < 0:
            tmp = 0
    new_number += str(tmp)
```